# Android - save multiple record affecting multiple tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a project have to save some register into to database SQLite, but at the same time insert into another table.

Example:

```
tables : contact_enc contact_det
contact_enc columns: id, name, telefono
contact_det columns: id, id_ce, name, address, status
```

I need to insert into `contact_enc` the field and same times `contact_det` the field.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use two insert operations

Comment: ...and wrap the two inserts in a transaction, so you can be sure that either they both succeed or both fail, and don't leave the database in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO contact_enc yourdatabase"; 
long lastID = this.database.execSQL(sql); 

int lastInsertId = Integer.ValueOf(lastId);

if(lastInsertId > 0) {
    String sql2 = "INSERT INTO contact_det (id_ce) VALUES(lastInsertId)"; 
    this.database.execSQL(sql2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` column of `contact_enc` is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, you can use the [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function, like the following SQL statements, to be executed one immediately after the other:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO contact_enc (name, telefono) VALUES (:Name, :Telefono);
INSERT INTO contact_det (id_ce, name, address, status) SELECT last_insert_rowid(), :Name, :Address, :Status;
COMMIT;
```

(Note that `:Name`, `:Telefono`, `:Name`, `:Address`, and `:Status` are parameters bound by name. If you’d rather bind the parameters by number, which seems easier to do in Android, just replace each placeholder by a ? question mark).